# Acid fog on Mars?

Tags: mars, weather, spirit

Recently a [study](http://news.discovery.com/space/acid-fog-likely-dissolved-rocks-on-mars-151102.htm) on the data from the **Spirit** rover in Gusev crater suggested that there may be acid fog changing the rocks.

What exactly is this acid fog?

How is it formed on Mars and where?

Is it a potential hazard for astronauts and Mars missions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's anybody's guess until we get a chemical analysis - but we can make some informed guesses.

One obvious solution is $\mathrm{CO_2 + H_2O \rightarrow H_2CO_3} $ which is a very weak acid, but an acid nevertheless, though I doubt it could contribute much to erosion.

The detected perchlorates in soil though are a different matter. There's a range of reactions of $\mathrm{KClO_4}$ and $\mathrm{NaClO_4}$ with water and input of electrons (from cosmic radiation) that result in a range of chlorine-based acids:  $\mathrm{HCl}$, $\mathrm{HClO}$, $\mathrm{HClO_2}$, $\mathrm{HClO_3}$ - and these are acids that can cause serious damage.